# Magic method "findBy<field name>" on Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I am using the Model and Entity class to manage users with Codeigniter4.

Thus, with the "`find (<id>)`" method I can easily find the data of a user through his id.

Is it possible to use a magical method, like on Doctrine, to find a user through email?

```
findByEmail(<email>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think CI4 directly support Doctrine.

What you can do is

```
$users = $userModel->where('email', $email)->find();
```

---

FYI - [Using CodeIgniter’s Model - codeigniter.com](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html#using-codeigniter-s-model)

Answer (score 0):

You can make this behavior yourself using PHP's magic method `__call`. Without trying to give too much away, create your implementation of this method inside of your User Model (or Base Model, if you want it for all Models):

```
  public function __call($name, $args) {
    if (substr($name, 0, 6) == "findBy") {
      $col = strtolower(substr($name, 6));
      if (in_array($col, $this->allowedFields) && isset($args[0])) {
        return $this->where($col, $args[0])->findAll();
      }
    }
    return NULL;
  }
```

This makes a lot of assumptions (Camelcase method naming, lowercase column naming, column name is in $this->allowedFields, single argument) but should lead you on the right path. More about magic methods here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call